# Recursive Method StackOverflow Error - Minesweeper

Tags: recursion, stack-overflow, minesweeper

I am writing the recursive method for a minesweeper game and I am encountering a stackOverflow error in the recursive method that clears out empty spaces, The error does not occur when checking for 3 of the surrounding spaces but only when checking all eight. Can you please help identify the issue?

The stack trace is :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8419)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.setText(AbstractButton.java:306)
    at Minesweeper.Minesweeper.showTile(Minesweeper.java:105)
    at Minesweeper.Minesweeper.clearEmpty(Minesweeper.java:137)
    at Minesweeper.Minesweeper.clearEmpty(Minesweeper.java:177)
```

The class:

```
public class Minesweeper implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Minesweeper");
    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
    JButton solve = new JButton("Solve");
    JToggleButton[][] buttons = new JToggleButton[20][20];
    int[][] counts = new int [20][20];
    Container grid = new Container();
    final int MINE = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Minesweeper();
    }

    public Minesweeper()
    {
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(reset, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(solve, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        reset.addActionListener(this);
        solve.addActionListener(this);
        grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 20));
        for (int r = 0; r < buttons.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < buttons[0].length; c++) {
                buttons[r][c] = new JToggleButton();
                buttons[r][c].addActionListener(this);
                grid.add(buttons[r][c]);
                buttons[r][c].setSize(frame.getWidth() / 20, frame.getHeight() / 22);
            }
        }
        frame.add(grid,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        addRandomMines();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addRandomMines()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> mineList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int x = 0; x < counts.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < counts[0].length; y++){
                mineList.add((x*100)+y);
            }
        }
        counts = new int[20][20];
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            int choice = (int)(Math.random()*mineList.size());
            counts[mineList.get(choice)/100][mineList.get(choice)%100] = MINE;
            mineList.remove(choice);
        }


        for (int x = 0; x < counts.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < counts[0].length; y++){
                if (counts[x][y]!=MINE) {
                    int mineCount = 0;
                    if (x > 0 && y > 0 && counts[x - 1][y - 1] == MINE)
                        mineCount++;
                    if (y > 0 && counts[x][y - 1] == MINE)
                        mineCount++;
                    if (x > 0 && counts[x - 1][y] == MINE)
                        mineCount++;
                    if (x < counts.length - 1 && counts[x + 1][y] == MINE)
                        mineCount++;
                    if (y < counts.length - 1 && counts[x][y + 1] == MINE)
                        mineCount++;
                    if (x < counts.length - 1 && y < counts.length - 1 && counts[x + 1][y + 1] == MINE)
                        mineCount++;
                    if (x > 0 && y < counts.length - 1 && counts[x - 1][y + 1] == MINE)
                        mineCount++;
                    if (x < counts.length - 1 && y > 0 && counts[x + 1][y - 1] == MINE)
                        mineCount++;
                    counts[x][y] = mineCount;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void showTile(int r, int c)
    {
        if (counts[r][c] == 0) {
            buttons[r][c].setText("");
            buttons[r][c].setSelected(true);
        }
        else if (counts[r][c]==MINE) {
            buttons[r][c].setForeground(Color.red);
            buttons[r][c].setText("X");
            buttons[r][c].setSelected(true);
        }
        else {
            buttons[r][c].setText(counts[r][c] + "");
            if (counts[r][c]==1)
                buttons[r][c].setForeground(Color.blue);
            else if (counts[r][c]==2)
                buttons[r][c].setForeground(Color.magenta);
            else if (counts[r][c]==3)
                buttons[r][c].setForeground(Color.green);
            buttons[r][c].setSelected(true);
        }
    }

    public void lostGame() {
        for (int x = 0; x < buttons.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < buttons[0].length; y++) {
               if (counts[x][y]==MINE) {
                   showTile(x, y);
               }
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearEmpty(ArrayList<Integer> toClear)
    {
        if (toClear.size()==0){
            return;
        }
        else {
            int x = toClear.get(0)/100;
            int y = toClear.get(0)%100;
            toClear.remove(0);
            if (counts[x][y]==0) {
                if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
                    showTile(x-1,y-1);
                    if (counts[x-1][y-1]==0)
                        toClear.add((x-1)*100 + (y-1));
                }
                if (y > 0) {
                    showTile(x,y-1);
                    if (counts[x][y-1]==0)
                        toClear.add(x*100 + (y-1));
                }
                if (x <counts.length-1 && y > 0) {
                    showTile(x+1,y-1);
                    if (counts[x+1][y-1]==0)
                        toClear.add((x+1)*100 + (y-1));
                }
                if (x > 0) {
                    showTile(x-1,y);
                    if (counts[x-1][y]==0)
                        toClear.add((x-1)*100 + y);
                }
                if (x <counts.length-1 && y > 0) {
                    showTile(x+1,y);
                    if (counts[x+1][y]==0)
                        toClear.add((x+1)*100 + y);
                }
                if (x > 0 && y < counts[0].length-1) {
                    showTile(x-1,y+1);
                    if (counts[x-1][y+1]==0)
                        toClear.add((x-1)*100 + (y+1));
                }
                if (y < counts[0].length-1) {
                    showTile(x,y+1);
                    if (counts[x][y+1]==0)
                        toClear.add(x*100 + (y+1));
                }
                if (x <counts.length-1 && y < counts[0].length-1) {
                    showTile(x+1,y+1);
                    if (counts[x+1][y+1]==0)
                        toClear.add((x+1)*100 + (y+1));
                }
            }
            clearEmpty(toClear);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource().equals(reset)) {
            for (int r = 0; r < buttons.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < buttons[0].length; c++) {
                    buttons[r][c].setSelected(false);
                    buttons[r][c].setText("");
                }
            }
            addRandomMines();
        } else if (event.getSource().equals(solve)) {

        } else {
            for (int r = 0; r < buttons.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < buttons[0].length; c++) {
                    if (event.getSource().equals(buttons[r][c])) {
                        if (counts[r][c] == MINE) {
                            showTile(r, c);
                            lostGame();
                        }
                        else if (counts[r][c] == 0) {
                            ArrayList<Integer> toClear = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            toClear.add(r*100+c);
                            clearEmpty(toClear);
                        }
                        else {
                            showTile(r, c);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace please.

Comment: Please add it to yyour Question using the edit function. Not as comment

Comment: Please show us the exact line where in your code where the exception occurs (which is line 105?).

Comment: Your toClear list keeps growing while you only remove 1 item per iteration. Which points to the fact that your if structure aren't correct.

Comment: It just points to the recursive call and the <code>if (counts[r][c]==1)</code> line in the showTile method

Comment: Your list has lots of duplicates which also points to the fact that your if structures aren't complete/correct.

Comment: @User404 how do I fix my if structure

Comment: @MitchellSayer the solution is not to *fix* you `if`s but to think about your list (as explained in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're using the wrong algorithm...

Try to use an iterative instead of an recursive approach.

As User404 already mentioned your current algorithm keeps the list growing...

For your implementation: you have 400 tiles. Assuming (worst case) all tiles are empty you call your method `clearEmpty()` once. You will find out that all 8 neighbors are empty so you add this 8 neighbors to the list while only removing the first one. Now you pass the array to the method again (2nd call) and will find 8 neighbors for the first entry again. So your 3rd call will have a list with 15 tiles.

**Real problem**

This way you will never come to an end as you never check if the current checked tile is already cleared but you only add to the list more than you will ever remove.

**Solution**

At least you should check if the tile you want to add to the list is already cleared or is already in the list.

You example is a clear example why recursive algorithms should be used with care as the termination is difficult sometimes and also you have to take care that no work is done multiple times.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try checking if it is already cleared and If not, I will give it a different approach.